# Why are Eurotunnel tickers 33% cheaper if you are 'resident in the UK'?

Tags: eurotunnel

When you go to book a ticket on their web site you have to give your details including your country of residence.

For the same trip, if your country of residence is the UK the price will be 25% to 35% cheaper than if you are not resident in the UK.

Anybody know why ?

Is there any check at anytime to verify your country of residence ?

You can see for yourself at https://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/home/

Comment: Do you have a source indicating this?

Comment: You've added a link saying we can see for ourselves there, but it's just a link to the homepage. I don't see any mention of cheaper prices for UK residents, and indeed when i searched ticket prices (somewhat arbitrarily: travelling tomorrow, returning the day after, with a car under 6ft, no trailer or bikes) the prices were the same regardless of whether I selected UK, France, or "other countries" as country of residence. Do you have a source which *actually* shows that such a difference exists?

Comment: There is indeed a price difference, but it is a little hard to see.  I tried a daytrip on 16 Jan 2019, middle of the day, regular car, no caravan or roof rack: A UK resident starting in Folkstone is charged £30; a French resident starting in Calais is charged €42 (~£37.50 at current exchange rates).  However, I think this is more to do with the outdated exchange rate they use (£1 = €1.40) than the residency/nationality of the traveller.

Comment: Interestingly, the fare finder makes some assumptions - 
that UK residents will want to depart from Folkstone; 
that other country resident will want to depart from Calais;
and if you depart from the UK you want to pay in GBP;
but if you depart from the EU you want to pay in EUR.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. the only way to 'prove' this is to carry out 2 searches for the same trip with different 'residency'. I'm looking at a trip over the holidays and it's showing a 30% difference. I am a Brit but I live abroad. I'm tempted to enter a UK address as residency.. how are they going to check ? I have my British passport

Comment: @nick strange, the fair finder doesn't do that for me when I switch residency to France. It *does* ask if I’m sure I want to start from Folkestone, but prices are still shown in GBP (and identical to the prices shown for uk residents). Being an exchange rate thing rather than a residency matter seems plausible though, if prices were roughly equivalent but haven’t been updated in a while the GBP price could certainly be quite a bit cheaper now.

Comment: mm... ok.. could be a currency conversion issue... (a bit.. )... still not totally convinced.. thanks for all the answers

Comment: @Realin - "... how are they going to check ?".  They're not going to check.  When booking, you don't have to prove your residency.  However, you probably do have to enter your billing address if you pay by card; and when you arrive, they can probably take _guesses_ at your residency based on your passport nationality and vehicle registration.